# upload image in db mysql vs upload it to server

Tags: mysql, image, web

which of the two is much better when it comes to uploading the image. is it uploading it to database using datatype blob or uploading it to server and saving the filename to database. are there any significant differences between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way (IMO) is to store it into a service such as AWS S3 (Amazon Web Services Simple Storage Service) and store a link to it in your database there.

Advantages of this are that you can use CloudFront in future to speed up serving your data and there's no need to do a database BLOB read to serve data, and finally, S3 is very fast.